# Rapidminer's Multilayer Perceptron strange results

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, data-mining, rapidminer, perceptron

I have a dataset of 1000 examples, 500 positive and 500 negative. I am validating them with 0.7 split ratio, and then put them on rapidminers MP with default parameter except having two layers of 25 nodes.

However when I validate it all my prediction are negative I have no idea why? Even with poor optimized MP (like in this very example) I should have getting at least a single positive prediction.

Well, it's the first time I am doing this on rapidminer and probably it's a very basic mistake but I can't find it.

[image]

[image]

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.008">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="split_validation" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="112" name="Validation (6)" width="90" x="112" y="255">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="neural_net" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Neural Net" width="90" x="69" y="30">
            <list key="hidden_layers">
              <parameter key="Layer" value="25"/>
              <parameter key="Layer2" value="25"/>
            </list>
            <parameter key="training_cycles" value="100"/>
            <parameter key="shuffle" value="false"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="training" to_op="Neural Net" to_port="training set"/>
          <connect from_op="Neural Net" from_port="model" to_port="model"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_training" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_through 1" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Apply Model (6)" width="90" x="45" y="30">
            <list key="application_parameters"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="performance" compatibility="5.3.008" expanded="true" height="76" name="Performance (6)" width="90" x="147" y="30"/>
          <connect from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model (6)" to_port="model"/>
          <connect from_port="test set" to_op="Apply Model (6)" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Apply Model (6)" from_port="labelled data" to_op="Performance (6)" to_port="labelled data"/>
          <connect from_op="Performance (6)" from_port="performance" to_port="averagable 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_model" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_test set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_through 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: How did you split the data? As you mentioned you used split ratio .7, so the training set should have both positive and negative instances (and from the validation it seems it was quite well split). Is it possible that the order of them might influenced the MP learning?

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate on "how did I split the data" since as I and you mentioned I did an 0.7 split. And by order what do you mean?The order how they were inserted? If so I used the shuffled sampling option.

Comment: It seems you were not using shuffled sampling (`<parameter key="shuffle" value="false"/>`), though it is possible there were a bug in the version you used. I tried with the Ripley dataset with shuffle, 1000 iteration, .05 momentum and error epsilon 5e-6 and got prediction to both classes with RapidMiner 5.3.15. You might check your data with newer version of RM.

Comment: Hmm I meant shuffled sampling on the validation part, in the NN itself I am not using it, I forgot that was a parameter there.

Answer (score 0):

So far you process looks quite good. The interesting thing is: What happens to your data? To investigate this you could set some breakpoints and examine your samples. A breakpoint set before the NN-learner will show you how the training set looks like, another one set before the model applier lets you inspect the test set.
To ensure a proper class distribution you may enable stratified sampling for the validation operator. The shuffle option of the NN-learner allows the operator to shuffle the training set before training the model. This is useful just in case your data items are already sorted, which can lead to an inappropriate model.